# I cannot reach from a browser to ec2 instance in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I wrote a very simple spring-boot application and packed it in Docker.

The content of docker file is:

```
FROM openjdk:13
ADD target/HelloWorld-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar HelloWorld.jar
EXPOSE 8085
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "HelloWorld.jar"]
```

I pushed it to docker hub.

I created a new EC2 instance on aws. Then I connected to it and typed the following commands:

```
sudo yum update -y
sudo yum install docker -y
sudo service docker start
sudo docker run -p 80:8085 ****/docker-hello-world
```

The last command gave many messages on the screen that said that spring-boot application is running.

Looks great. However, when I opened my browser and typed: "http://ec2-54-86-87-68.compute-1.amazonaws.com/" (public DNS of EC2 machine).
I got "This site can’t be reached".

Do you know what I did wrong?

Edit: security groups that regard this machine are "default" and the following group that I defined:

[image]

Inside the EC2 machine, I typed:"curl localhost:8085" and got:
"curl: (52) Empty reply from server"

Comment: Check if container is up and running using **docker ps** command. If the container is running, then check it's logs using command **docker logs <container_id> -f**

Comment: @Nitish. I checked. It's running.

Comment: Is the container running with the right image? Any errors in the log? Check with **netstat -plnt** if it's listening on port 80. Also try **curl localhost** and **curl localhost:8085**. You should definitely get some o/p when you curl port 8085 or else the application inside the container is not running on port 8085

Comment: I typed "curl localhost:8085" and got 
curl: (52) Empty reply from server

Comment: I suspect your jar is not running on port 8085. Run **docker exec -it <container_id> bash**, install netstat or ss and check on which port your application is listening. You can directly run a command inside container using **dokcer exec <container_id> "<command>"

Comment: **curl localhost:8085** shouldn't fetch an o/p, I got confused due to similar app running on my machine. Sorry for that. Did you get any o/p for **curl localhost**?

Comment: Thanks. I solved it. I wrote an answer.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl query for "amazon-web-services" tag here - none of questions are about programming.

Comment: @nickolay.laptev The sad fact that there are indeed many off-topic questions here does not justify posting yet another one.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I would say it's a sign something doesn't work in the system and it's not a problem of individual author. For example people should care about tons of stackexchange sites, that they obviously don't care. I'm not sure about off-topic part, AWS is not about programming, it's always about infrastructure. Those who created this tag made such questions completely legal.

Comment: @nickolay.laptev The *first two sentences* in the [tag:amazon-web-services] tag description say: *"ONLY QUESTIONS ABOUT PROGRAMMING ARE ON-TOPIC. General server help can be obtained at https://serverfault.com"*

Comment: @MartinPrikryl agree, I missed this point. I compared the number of created questions for AWS tag here and at serverfault - roughly 3 vs 50 questions. I don't remember programming related questions with AWS tag (and cannot imagine such questions to be honest). So this doesn't work as a system according to numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your port's inbound traffic is enabled for your local IP address in your ec2 instance security group configuration

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-security-groups.html#adding-security-group-rule

Comment: I changed the allowed ports. Edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you allowed inbound traffic for port 8085 in your security group configuration? That should be the first thing to check.

Comment: I changed the allowed ports. Edited the question.

Comment: No need to open port 8085. Since host port 80 is mapped to port 8085, opening tcp 80 is enough.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

It was port issues. 
Instead of running

```
sudo docker run -p 80:8085 ****/docker-hello-world
```

I had to run:

```
sudo docker run -p 8085:8080 ****/docker-hello-world
```

This command says: "take the application that runs on port 8080 in the application and put it on port 8085 on docker".

I opened the browser and browsed to: "http://ec2-18-207-188-57.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8085/hello" and got the response I expected.